# Using Textmerg Field and Code128 Macro

Tags: barcodes

I am trying to create a Code 128 barcode in a LaTeX document, and want to create it based on one of the fields I am using in the `textmerg` package,

```
\code{\MailId}
```

but am receiving

```
The input token "\MailId" is not included in Code 128 table, will ignored.
```

And, true to its word, I get an empty barcode. I can't figure out if I need to “escape” it somehow? Just a line or two before, I use this same field to grab an image by that name, so I know (believe?) it isn’t null.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how much you search, you always find the answer just after posting a question:

```
\expandafter\code\expandafter{\MailId}
```

[ISBN barcodes using labels and textmerg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416460/isbn-barcodes-using-labels-and-textmerg)

Comment: If this is the same user as the one asking the question, you may want to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `barracuda`, a Lua-Based package:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
gigi@mail.com
luca@mailbox.com
geronimo@mailbox.com
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{barracuda}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\begin{document}
\Fields{\MailId}
\Merge{\jobname.dat}{\barracuda{code128}{\MailId}}
\end{document}
```

Remember to compile with `lualatex` or any other LaTeX format with any of Lua-Based typesetting TeX engine. `barracuda` does not have dependences and can be used directly with no specific format. Is also possible to save barcode graphics in SVG.